# Send file CURL + PHP 7

Tags: php, curl

I use code for send zip file and this work good:

```
$file = ''.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/projects/file.zip';
$data = array(
    "file" => new CURLFile($file),
    "data" => '{"title":"Test"}'
);
$handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Content-type: multipart/form-data;',
));
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$final = curl_exec($handle);
$response = json_decode($final, true);
curl_close ($handle);
```

But when I send a file with the .keystore extension, nothing works. I do not receive errors on the server.

How do I properly send such a file?

Comment: The filename (including extension) or even content of a file shouldn't make any difference to how you send it; all `CURLFile` is doing is reading the contents of the file and transmitting it in a suitable encoding.

Comment: You're right. I spent a lot of time. The error was in the file path.)

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
$file = ''.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/projects/file.zip';
$mime = mime_content_type($file);
$info = pathinfo($file);
$name = $info['basename'];
$output = new CURLFile($file, $mime, $name);

$data = array(
    "file" => $output,
    "data" => '{"title":"Test"}'
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
   $result = curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```